# SSL Socket client in Golang

Tags: sockets, ssl, go

I'm trying to connect to a server through a socket using an ssl certificate. I have the private key and the certificate needed to connect to the server, i have looked around for something to help me write this code in Go but i have not found anything helpful. Here is the code i write so far, but it does not seem to get me anywhere, it seems to be sending data(tls.dial) before getting to the actual data, which forces the server to reply with some encrypted data which i am unable to check.

```
func main() {
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert.pem", "key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)
    }
    config := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}, InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "1.2.3.4:1234", &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client: dial: %s", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    log.Println("client: connected to: ", conn.RemoteAddr())

    state := conn.ConnectionState()
    for _, v := range state.PeerCertificates {
        fmt.Println(x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(v.PublicKey))
        fmt.Println(v.Subject)
    }
    log.Println("client: handshake: ", state.HandshakeComplete)
    log.Println("client: mutual: ", state.NegotiatedProtocolIsMutual)

    message := "data"
    n, err := io.WriteString(conn, message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client: write: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("client: wrote %q (%d bytes)", message, n)

    reply := make([]byte, 256)
    n, err = conn.Read(reply)
    log.Printf("client: read %q (%d bytes)", string(reply[:n]), n)
    log.Print("client: exiting")
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, what do you mean that the server replies with "some encrypted data which [you are] unable to check" . Please show what you expect to happen, and what you actually saw.

Comment: I am getting the error "client: dial: EOF", the request is hanging at the tls.dial and is not going farther, so my data is not even sent yet. EDIT: I expect to send data over an encrypted socket using a certificate and a key.

Comment: So the server is _not_ sending back data, and just closing the connection? What does the server log for the connection attempt?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to the server nor to the logs. I'm sure this has nothing to do with the server, this code used to be written in Java, now i'm trying the same thing in Go.

Comment: If the server is closing the connection immediately, you haven't provided any information here that can help. My only other guess is that the server only supports an old TLS version or unsupported cipher suites and doesn't understand or accept the client connection, but you have to troubleshoot that yourself.